# Javascript to cut <u> to <u> and add it to new DIV

Tags: javascript, sap-successfactors

I am currently working with a Website Design kit to create Job Descriptions (SAP SuccessFactors Career Site Builder) so my options of reqriting everything are basically nonexistent. I need to force everything with CSS and JavaScript. Yay. The Kit is very basic and does not allow to add columns in between.

The goal is to have the layout like this:

---------- General stuff ------------

-- Tasks ------------- Requirements -

--------- More General Stuff --------

The second "More General Stuff" can be ignored as it's in a new element.

The Code for the Element containing General Stuff, Tasks and Requirement looks as follows:

```
<span class="jobdescription">
     <div id="general Stuff">....</div>
     <p><u>TASKS</u></p>
     <ul>
         <li>Lorem Ipsum 1</li>
         <li>Lorem Ipsum 2</li>
     </ul>
     <p> </p>
     <p><u>REQUIREMENTS</u></p>
     <ul>
         <li>Lorem Ipsum 1</li>
         <li>Lorem Ipsum 2</li>
     </ul>
</span>
```

My first idea was to add a new DIV, aplice all  and write them into the new DIV:

```
<div id="custJobPosting" style="display:none;">
  <div class="job-details-container"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".jobdescription u").slice(0, 3).each(function (i) {
    $(".job-details-container").append($("<div class='job-details-section'></div>").append($(this)).append($(".jobdescription ul").first()));
  });

  $(".job-details-container").append($(".jobdescription p").first());
  var jobDetailsSectionTemplate = $("<div class='job-details-section'></div>");
  $(".jobdescription u").slice(-4).each(function (i) {
    if (i === 3) return;
    var headerText = $(this).text();
    var paragraph = $(this).closest("p").clone();
    var closestEl = paragraph.text(paragraph.text().trim().replace(headerText, '')).append($(".jobdescription ul").first());
    $(".job-details-container").append(jobDetailsSectionTemplate.clone().append($(this)).append(closestEl));
  });

  $(".job-details-container").append($(".jobdescription u:last-of-type").css("width", "100%"));

  $(".jobdescription").html($("#custJobPosting"));

  $("#custJobPosting").show();
</script>
```

I then just style the custJobPosting and job-details-container to get the 2 Column look.
While this works like a charm, it cuts the <div id="general Stuff>.... and does not display it anymore.

Any ideas wher eI went wrong or any ideas to do it easier?

Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: Ids can't have spaces in the name. It should probably be `generalstuff`. Also, is there are reason you can't just change the HTML directly?

Comment: The ID is just a placeholder to convey the general idea. :)
I cannot change the HTML directly due to the system being bound to a website design kit like Word Press where you have standard Plugins (like "Picture") where you then add some content (like selecting a picture to be displayed).

The Design Kit then has standard CSS to display those Plugins which I can overwrite. I can add custom plugins with own HTML code but the content I am pushing here comes from a different System that populates a Token (JobDescription here, converted to the "jobdescription" Span by the Web Design Kit).